# Установил различные библиотеки через pip например matplotlib и numpy при их вызове встречается такая ошибка

Tags: python, pip

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\asdad.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy
  File "D:\gavnojopa\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 305, in <module>
    _win_os_check()
  File "D:\gavnojopa\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 302, in _win_os_check
    raise RuntimeError(msg.format(__file__)) from None
RuntimeError: The current Numpy installation ('D:\\gavnojopa\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py') fails to pass a sanity check due to a bug in the windows runtime. See this issue for more information:
```

Comment: при том что когда я проверял в командной строке через pip freeze библиотеки были точно установлены

Comment: Текст ошибки не полностью скопирован

Comment: Как каталог назвали - так оно и поплыло. Нда. А так да - зря обрезали ошибку, сам как-раз суть после этого должна быть.

Comment: нельзя tinyurl добавить в stackoverflow

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл ответ.
pip install numpy==1.19.3